# Como solventar el error undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'

Tags: c++, socket, dev-c++

He pensado ¿cómo puedo a través de un programa en c++ acceder a páginas web? una cosa llevo a la otra y me encontré leyendo sobre **Sockets** en la página de microsoft [Creando una aplicación básica de Winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737629(v=vs.85).aspx) e [inicializando Winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738566(v=vs.85).aspx). Pues coloque todos los códigos en Dev c++ pero me arrojó este error

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
```

El código que use fue este:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

  return 0;
}
```

Busque en SO en ingles y encontré varias preguntas sobre este tema. Las respuestas que ofrecían hablan que el `#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")` que coloco al principio del programa no es valido para el compilador gcc sino solo para visual c++ y que en ves de ello tengo que adicionar la librería manualmente
a través del makefile colocando `-L"ws2_32"` sin embargo intente ponerlo en algunos lugares y los resortes seguían saltando tras cada compilación

El IDE que utilizo es DEV C++ 5.11 y estoy bajo entorno windows 8, me gustaría saber como agregar las librerías para ese IDE y cual libreria debería añadir

Muchas gracias por su atención. Escucho sugerencias

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma comment(...)
```

Esta instrucción solo funciona en el compilador de Microsoft. MinGW simplemente lo ignora.

Lamento decirte que tienes que editar el proyecto para incluir la línea

```
-L"ws2_32"
```

En las opciones de enlazado.

Comment: He logrado solventar el error de esta manera; primero busque la ubicación del archivo _libws2_32.a_ luego fui a **proyecto** -> **opciones del proyecto** -> la pestaña **argumentos del programa** -> click en el boton **agregar libreria u objeto** y busque la ubicacion del archivo _libws2_32.a_  y lo agregué. :)

Comment: @JacoboCordova Esa fórmula es peligrosa ya que si tienes diferentes compiladores puedes acabar enlazando con la librería equivocada

Comment: Ok, Gracias por responder, entiendo que hay peligro si tengo diferentes compiladores.. pero ¿cómo puedo saberlo?

Comment: @JacoboCordova es complicado de decir. Si la máquina es tuya es más sencillo llevar el control, pero no siempre será así